# How to get the return value of pipe and executable on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, pipe, cat

I am running some unit tests which involve piping into my executable, like this.

```bash
cat text.txt | my_exe --options
```

Running these commands, how do I get the return value of `my_exe`? Even when `my_exe` returns failure, the return value is discarded. I assume the return value of `cat` is prioritized instead.

Asked another way, how do I execute the above pipe command to give the same return value as :

```bash
cat text.txt && my_exe --options
```

ty!

edit : Using the traditional `cmd`.

Comment: Which command-line shell are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "the return value is discarded" and how are you checking for it?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Edited the question with the answer, `cmd`.

@harrymc Unit tests are ran on a CI server, which notifies of failure of the command if return value != 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd` DOES set the exit status for a pipeline to the rightmost component and the (or any) other component is NOT 'prioritized' or even considered. Observe:

```
c:\temp>echo exit 42 | cmd >NUL

c:\temp>echo %errorlevel%
42


c:\temp>cmd/c echo exit 42 | cmd >NUL

c:\temp>echo %errorlevel%
42


c:\temp>cmd/c "echo exit 42 && exit 17" | cmd >NUL

c:\temp>echo %errorlevel%
42


c:\temp>cmd/c exit 17 | cmd/c exit 0

c:\temp>echo %errorlevel%
0


c:\temp>cmd/c exit 11 | cmd/c exit 22 | cmd/c exit 33

c:\temp>echo %errorlevel%
33


c:\temp>cmd/c exit 11 | cmd/c exit 22 | cmd/c echo GOOD
GOOD

c:\temp>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

If you're getting a different result you must be doing something different than you show in your Q, but since we have no clue what that is, it's impossible to make any useful suggestions.

Comment: You are correct. The server was running `powershell` instead of `cmd`. Switching to `cmd` fixed the problem. Thank you for answering though!